# Android studio installation in Linux server

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to install android studio installed in a Linux distribution, particularly,  Ubuntu server but seems it is not supported and I am getting errors.

In short, Is it possible to install android studio in Linux server.

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari which link?

Comment: follow this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu

Comment: please share the errors - otherwise it is not clear how to troubleshoot

Comment: added the right tag. paraphrased the question.